# Landing in an airport other than destination due to bad weather

Tags: refunds, emergencies, lot-polish-airlines

During my flight from Warsaw to Yerevan, the aircraft had to land in Tbilisi because of bad weather conditions in Yerevan. When we landed the captain declared that we can go back to Warsaw or stay in Tbilisi, however he emphasized that they are not going to organize anything for transporting us from Tbilisi to Yerevan. Neither they provided any approximate date about the possible return flight from Warsaw to Yerevan, or information about accommodation in Warsaw. Eventually I chose to stay at Tbilisi and got to Yerevan after 12 hours, because of many delays during luggage retrieval.

Obviously, diversion to another country is a valid reason for a delay, however not providing any information about passengers condition after returning to Warsaw, and neither being able to handle the transportation with a bus from Tbilisi to Warsaw seems to be not very customer friendly.

I am not sure if it makes sense to claim a refund for the ticket, and will be really thankful to know about your similar experience.

Comment: Poland is in the EU the last time I checked. Which means you're probably due a refund and a _lot_ more on top of that, for the airline's failure to actually transport you to your destination.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the airlines brought you to Yerevan at the end of the day. The first messages were certainly confusing but what happened then? You booked the bus yourself? Or did the airline arrange it for you?

Comment: @pnuts The way I read it, he had to arrange his own transportation to Yerevan. But perhaps that might not be the case.

Comment: I had to wait for almost 2 hours until I got my luggage, and then thanks god one of the passengers had contacts of a bus driver, and she could arrange the bus for us. We did not get any support from the airline after we left the aircraft. We knew they had a representative in that airport, but we received no attention.

Comment: Oh no, they suggested to go back on the same plane to warsaw, or to stay at tbilisi and take care of yourself however you want.

Comment: I wonder what airline this was

Comment: @pnuts I have already submitted a request for a merge , thanks for the good advice though

Comment: @AleksG LOT polish airlines

Comment: Frankly, I expected more of LOT.  I have flown with them between Warsaw and Tbilisi and they've been great in relation to any delays.  When I missed my connection in Warsaw due to delays in Tbilisi, they paid for two meals in Warsaw and put me on the next flight to my destination.  They were as apologetic as it could possibly be, although the delay wasn't technically their fault (bad weather at Tbilisi).  Are you sure you understood the message correctly?

Comment: I updated the title of your question to better reflect its content, as "emergency landing" in many people's mind mean something completely different (e.g. I experienced an emergency landing on a remote military base once due to fire on board)

Comment: @AleksG They refused to organize Tbilisi - Yerevan transportation, they offered only flight back to Warsaw. I am really sorry, I did an important mistake and since I am logged in as an anonymous used by mistake (instead of logging into my stack exchange profile) I can't make an edit before they merge my accounts :(

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel no worries, I edited the question

Comment: This is terrible service. We have been diverted due to bad weather but were all provided with food, lodging, transportation and exemption from immigration (this surprised me the most) at the unscheduled stop. The next day we were taken to our final destination where we completed the immigration process at our intended destination.

Comment: Very important point missing: Did they fly the passengers in the same aircraft back to Warsaw?  Meaning, they diverted to Tbilisi, refueled, and flew back to Warsaw.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go on a whim and try to answer as best as I understand the question. If I misunderstood something, please let me know and I'll either change the answer or delete it if I can't answer the question any longer.

The airline did offer to fly you back to a location where they could provide you with any necessary support.  The reason they couldn't give you an answer about when they'd be able to transport you from Warsaw to Yerevan was because they can't predict the weather.  If you flew with them back to Warsaw, they would do their best to get you to Yerevan as soon as practical.  Although for weather related delays it's not strictly required, I suspect they would even provide you with some meal vouchers in Warsaw airport.  The airline did not refuse to continue your journey - they just couldn't do it at that time due to external circumstances - and they were trying to do their best.

It is *very* expensive for an airline to land a plane in a non-destination airport, for any reason, plus keeping the plane at the airport also costs them money, therefore they needed to get the plane back in the air as soon as possible.  Very likely the only reason they even landed was that they didn't have enough fuel to fly back to Warsaw.

You effectively voided your right for any refund or support by voluntarily aborting your travel and leaving the plane before reaching your destination.

While you can still attempt to write to the airline and request some compensation, technically they are not obligated to provide any - and I would be really surprised if they did.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, however don't you think they are somehow obliged to refund the expenses of getting from Tbilisi to Yerevan. Although it's very little money, I am just curious

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel technically they are not, as you voluntarily chose to do something different from their default offer. They did emphasise that they are not going to organise anything in terms of transport from Tbilisi to Yerevan, and that includes any payments. You chose to disembark anyway.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't look like they were even going to provide a return to Warsaw within a reasonable time period.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Actually they were going to return immediately, however still even if it's the case, they did not say where we are going to stay, and what they are going to cover if we decide to return. So I had really very limited information to make a decision of returning to Warsaw.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK as it is an international flight, the [Montreal Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal_Convention) should apply. It clearly states that the passengers have a contract to be transported from one point to another one

Extracts:

> Article 19 — Delay
>   The  carrier  is  liable  for  damage  occasioned  by  delay 
>   in  the  carriage  by  air  of  passengers,  baggage  or  cargo. 
>   Nevertheless,  the  carrier  shall  not  be  liable  for  damage 
>   occasioned by delay if it proves that it and its servants and 
>   agents took all measures that could reasonably be required 
>   to avoid the damage or that it was impossible for it or them 
>   to take such measures.

IMHO, it means that *it depends* on what was really said (and possibly written) at Tbilissi. If they said that you were on your own, full stop, they did not respect the contract and you can use MC to claim the full compensation of the damage in the limit of the carrier liability. But if they proposed to continue the travel via Warsaw (yes even if it was the start point) but simply could not say at that moment when you could reach Yerevan, they reasonably can argue that it was the best that they could do at that time.

If they did propose you to continue the travel by your own means and that they said that you would receive a compensation, fine, you can use that to claim for the compensation, but it looks like it is not what has happened.

If you choosed to stay in Tbilissi, you willingly stopped the travel. You could argue that you had to do that, because the carrier was not able to transport you to the normal destination in a delay that was acceptable for you. Maybe you could ask for the compensation for the delay that you could have asked if you had choosen to go back to Warsaw and had reached Yerevan with another flight from same company. But I would consult a lawyer before starting any legal action here...

You can evidently claim for a refund on a commercial agreement bases, specially if you can explain that you often use their services and would be sorry to now use another company.